# EDMX files and Changes in the database

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, edmx

I am working with a big WPF app and this app is using .edmx files to connect to the tables, views and procs n the database. We are in the process to increase some columns in some of those tables and increase the size of the parameters in a lot of procs that are being used in the WPF app. I'll have to right click in the .edmx and click in Update model from the database, but, i'm not sure if I have to select only the tables or tables, views and procs too.

Comment: Why not select all of the options to update everything in the EDMX?  When you try, does anything go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the model and choose Update model from the database. Then you should be able to go to the Refresh tab and refresh tables, views and/or stored procedures.

[image: Hightlighted Refresh tab]

Comment: I found more often than not better to simply delete the tables that were updated and import them again as I would get some weird errors in specific scenarios.

Comment: @MichaëlCorriveau-Côté , I'm in the same boat... it seems to be a 50/50 chance it will actually update properly from a database first generated entity.